# What design pattern uses this approach for naming POCO classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Ive got a library that handles the typical add/edit/update methods for an application.  Im wondering what design pattern calls for naming the POCO classes that bundle the data for is sent back and forth.  For example, one class might be similar to another, but needs to include a few other members for being sent back to the application vs the data that is sent in to be saved.

For example, this might be a POCO class that I would use to populate before in a library method before sending back to the app to be displayed/consumed.

```
public class CorporateDeptAssignmentInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DivisionKey { get; set; }
    public int DeptKey { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Corp_dept_from_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime Corp_dept_to_date { get; set; }            
}
```

On the other hand, if Im adding a new record, I might not want to populate all members.
I could either (a) make some members nullable or (b) create a new POCO class with a slightly different name for use with calling an update/add library method.

Are there any design patterns that mention the use of poco classes in either of the above ways?

Comment: View Model as in MVVM? Or Parameter Object Pattern?

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but when I create POCO objects _strictly_ for communicating over webservice layers (or inter-application layers), I call them "MyTypeDTO" (for [Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)). When reading/writing to the database layer, I call them "MyTypeDAO" ([Data Access Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)). The _application business logic_ has it named as "MyType" which converts to/from the DTO/DAO objects. Not sure about having an object strictly for _saving_ vs _reading/loading_ though.

Answer (score 0):

It's either an [Adapter, Decorator, or Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). That's where I think it's heading anyway. You are looking for a way to present something, with modifications/simplification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any specific design patterns for this scenario except the [Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), but if your domain object actually does allow nullable values, why are your pocos not designed in the same way?

Personally I would make two POCO classes if the loading and adding / updating process takes different data. Both of these classes usually have an ID property that resort to the same domain object. Sometimes it's also useful if one of these classes encapsulate the other POCO, but I don't have this kind of of situation often in my code.

If you have further questions, feel free to ask.